# how to add kubernetes liveness probe to check if a process is alive

Tags: kubernetes

I have a process running inside an Ubuntu container and would like to redeploy the container if the process gets killed. I added the following liveness probe in container spec

```
  livenessProbe:
    exec:
     command:
     - ps -ef | grep my_process_name
    initialDelaySeconds: 120
    periodSeconds: 30
```

However this doesnt work. When I do a `kubectl describe pods <pod_id>` I get the following event.

```
  1h    6m      20      {kubelet k8s-agent-71e8d996-0}        spec.containers{my_process_name}       Warning Unhealthy       Liveness       probe failed: rpc error: code = 13 desc = invalid header field value "oci runtime error: exec failed: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused \"exec: \\\"ps -ef | grep my_process_name\\\": executable file not found in $PATH\"\n"
```

And it keeps redeploying the container. If I bash into the container and do a 'ps -ef' it works but this doesnt
Whats a good way to use the liveness probe to check if a process is running or not ? Thanks.

Comment: Please provide more of the deployment configuration and also paste your config in a code block. As it is pasted now it is nearly impossible to help you as we cannot assess if there is a config formatting error.

Additionally, your current health check of `ps -ef | grep <ANYTHING>` will always exit with an exit code of `0` because grep will find the grep process itself. Does that make sense?

Comment: It does yes. I got it to work by doing the following. <br\>livenessProbe: <br/>
        exec: <br/>
         command: <br/>
         - /bin/bash <br/>
         - -c <br/>
         - ps -ef | grep my_process_name| grep -v "grep" <br/>

Comment: If you managed to solve your issue, please post such information as an answer. Although the code you put in the comment above can still be understood, it is completely unreadable. So if this solved your problem, consider posting it as an answer and mark it as accepted to show clearly that this is the solution.

Comment: Note: k8s monitors the liveness of a pod based on the execution of the PID 1 process within a node. Therefore, there is no need to include an additional liveness probe for the process that serves as the entrypoint. The container is presumed to have died by K8s if the PID 1 process exits and no liveness probe is defined.

Answer (score 10):

Make sure `ps` is installed. If it does not run: `apt-get update && apt-get install procps`

For the ease of copy-pasting OP's comment under the question :-).

Below, `worker.py` is the process that needs to be checked:

```
livenessProbe:
  exec:
    command:
    - /bin/bash
    - -c
    - ps -ef | grep worker.py | grep -v grep
  initialDelaySeconds: 10
  periodSeconds: 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Clearly `ps` is not being found in the path. You could try using `/bin/ps` instead of `ps`.